# Could not able to access IBM I AS/400 database from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, db2, pyodbc

Few days ago, I was able to access the database from Jupyter Notebook entering my credentials. Meanwhile, I changed the password and now I am trying to run the same code and obtaining an error. By using the new password, I can access the database from Advanced Query Tool where I have configured the database but I am uable to access it from Jupyter Notebook.
The code I am trying to access the databse as following:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
driver='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
system='System_name',
uid='id123',
pwd='password_12345')

sql = "Select * from MyDB.MyTable"
data = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
```

The error I am getting as following:

> InterfaceError   Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in
>
> 6     system='System_name',   7     uid='id123',
> ----> 8 pwd='password_12345')   9     sql = "Select * from MyDB.MyTable"
>
> InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC
> Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=8011 - CWBSY0011 - User
> id123 on system System_name has been disabled, Password length = 14,
> Prompt Mode = Never, System IP Address = XX.XXX.X.XX (8011)
> (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC
> Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=8011 - CWBSY0011 - **User
> id123 on system System_name has been disabled**, Password length = 14,
> Prompt Mode = Never, System IP Address = XX.XXX.X.XX (8011)')

Comment: You need to ask your admin to re-enable the user ( when the password is incorrect too many times, the account becomes locked (disabled)).  So get the admin to re-activate / enable /unlock the account.

Comment: @mao Thanks for your effort. It got resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by re-enabling the user account that had become disabled after too many incorrect password attempts. Per comment thread.